# How to tell visual studio code to get in new line when writing a macro?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual studio code. I've been using sublime text, and trying something new. In sublime you can write macros by recording them. In VSC i've found extension macros by geddski, and I am trying to write a macro for a new function these are the steps:
- go to end of the line, 
- write opening curly bracket, 
- enter new line, 
- and enter second new line, 
- write closing curly bracket, 
- than return to upper line.

My code looks like this:

```
"macros": {
        "curleyB": [
            "cursorEnd",
            {"command": "type", "args": {"text": " {"}},
            "enter"
                {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "}"}}
            "cursorUp"
        ]
```

But i get both opened and closed brackets one to another 
and cursor jumps a line above my function (i can't get VSC to eneter).
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is all you need:

```
"cursorEnd",
{
    "command": "type",
    "args": {"text": "{\n"},
},
```

VScode can automatically close that brace, so no need for the second type command or `cursorUp`.

I suggest looking at **snippets** - probably a better way to handle what you are trying to do.  For example: simply type

```
func
```

and one of the options is a snippet that looks like:

```
function name(params) {

}
```

with the `name` selected (enter your function name), then <kbd>Tab</kbd> and `params` will be selected for you to type over with your parameters.

Your usage is better suited to a simple snippet than a multicommand macro.  See [creating your own snippets in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks. I need a macro, 'cause I don't use it only with a function, but in objects, json and css often. So I needed macro to bnind it with a keybord shortcut. Now it works perfectly.